# Растянуть div на всю высоту родительского div

Tags: css, html

Здравствуйте. Есть три блока Div. Один родительский, второй внутри слева (для меню), второй внутри справа (для текста). Как можно растянуть правый внутренний блок (можно с левым) на всю высоту родительского блока. Сам родительский блок с фиксированной высотой не менее 1100px

Вот код:

```
<div id="wrapctr">
<div id="leftmenu"></div>
<div class="rightcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Вот что прописано в css:

```
    #wrapctr {
          width:80%;
          min-width: 700px;
          max-width: 1200px;
          background:#FFF;
          margin:0 auto;
          min-height:1100px;
          z-index:2;        
        }

    #leftmenu { 
      background: #FFF;
      float: left;
      width: 250px;
      list-style: none;
     }
.rightcontent {
      background: #FFF; 
      margin-left: 255px; 
     }
```

UPD:
На одной странице выдаются фотографии 12 штук по три в ряд, и страница имеет такой вид

```
<div id="wrapctr">
<div id="leftmenu"></div>
<div class="rightcontent">
//общий див
<div style="padding: 10px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between; background:white">
// на каждую картинку
<div style="float: left; padding: 10px; text-align: center; width: 257px;"><img src="../img/1625.jpg" width="200"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

И если на странице фотографий ровно 12, а не меньше, это полотно идет ниже правого дива

Comment: `height: 100%`?

Comment: Покажите код и стили картинок

Comment: @Cheg обновил в коде

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#wrapctr {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 700px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 1100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#leftmenu {
  background: #f00;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.rightcontent {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 255px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapctr">
  <div id="leftmenu"></div>
  <div class="rightcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это все подходит спасибо большое! Но на одной странице у меня внутри дива rightcontent есть еще один див, прописанный обычным стилем <div style="padding: 10px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between; background:white">
и он вылезает из этого правого дива, если там много текста

Comment: @Валерий покажите пример кода

Comment: добавил код в вопросе

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#wrapctr {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 700px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 1100px;
  height: 0px; /* просто чтобы был */
}

#leftmenu {
  background: #f00;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.rightcontent {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapctr">
  <div id="leftmenu"></div>
  <div class="rightcontent"></div>
</div>
```